# Help identifying this vine with green and white heart shaped leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, vines

I honestly have no idea what this plant is. It seems to be some type of vine. I took a few pictures i will put below. As you can see there is some other plant growing in the same pot with the long leaves. I want to clone this vine plant eventually, it looks really nice when the vines get long. So will I be able to clone this plant? And what exactly is it?

P.S, it has no flowers as far as I have seen, this confuses me since I see no form of reproduction on it.

[image]

A cluster of leaves

[image]

A vine

[image]

More vines

[image]

A new leaf, the leaves grow out of these whitish membranse on the sides of other leaves. This leads me to believe that only one leaf can come from a single leaf.

[image]

Another new leaf growing in.

[image]

The beginning of a leaf.

[image]

An overview

Comment: as well as pictures the part of the world where the vine is growing would be helpful too

Comment: In my house....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This plant has several names such as pothos or [Epipremnum aureum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum). Is an evergreen vine from the Australia/South Asia area and has become naturalized worldwide.  The reason you do not see any flowers on this due to it's life cycle.  Botanists saw two forms of the same plant:

- the juvenile form that you have that does not flower and whose leaves are not split
- the adult form that has much larger leaves that are split and does flower

As the shape of the leaves and the size of the two forms was quite different it took a while for botanists to conclude that they were the same species.

It is very easy to propagate and care for indoors.  Most potting soils are suitable and a schedule of regular watering when the soil gets dry is appropriate. You can propagate this plant by taking a cutting and putting it in a glass of water.

Maintenance of an established plant involves cutting back the stems close to the base.  Leave at least one node above the soil line and new growth will sprout from that point.

Insect pests include mealybug (white cottony tufts in the leaf axils) and thrip. If your plant gets any of these insect pests control is difficult.  You could try cutting the plant back hard so it has no leaves or dispose of it.

Comment: Thank you, I should probably move it into a shadier area now that I know what it is :-)

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Kevinsky, its Money plant (Epipremnum aureum). I am just showing the  propagation pictures by stem cutting and placing it in water filled bottle for few days till fresh roots develop. Then it is ready to be planted in the soil.

[image]

Zoomed View: Notice white colored roots growing! :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just put a potential clone in a cup of water but it only has one leaf on it so im not sure how it will turn out.

Comment: Most probably it will grow..! Just give it somesome, keep replacing half of the cup water with fresh water every few days.

Comment: Should I put liquid fertilizer in it?

Comment: I have never used any fertilizer on that..! so cannot answer you this; However mine has grown very well without that!