# Growing Epipremnum aureum stem roots on potted plant

Tags: roots, vines

I have an *Epipremnum aureum* (once rooted from a cutting) in a soil pot. It took some time, but then it grew at an incredible rate, with a thick stem (fingerbreadth) and large leaves.

On the other side, where it’s stuck in the soil, it’s decreasing in diameter (width like a slim pencil), and leaves are withering now for some time.

It’s healthy, bushy and leafy on one side, and waning on its only access to the ground. I don’t want to cut it in pieces just yet. I’d rather preserve its tiny canopy.

1. **Can I do anything to improve the stem’s health and thickness near the ground level?**
2. **Can I safely grow roots along the shoot parts (like covering it with soil to let it take root)?**

I’m afraid growing roots along the stem will confuse growth and water transport. Here’s a picture:

ﾠ  ﾠ

[image: Epipremnum aureum with lean stem near the soil (left) and bushy growth (right)]

---

**EDIT**: I knew about [layering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layering) *below* the ground, but I never heard of **[marcotting](https://www.google.com/search?q=marcotting&tbm=isch)** (a form of *air* layering). I didn’t cut the “bark” of the stem and—since I don’t have any Sphagnum handy—strapped some earthy garden moss around three clusters of nodes (here the stem gets thicker again). This surely isn’t optimal, but I’ll keep it moist and see if it takes root.

[image: Epipremnum aureum stem with moss attached to it]

Comment: If you wanted to try the more challenging methods of propagation your choice of layering is a good one.  If you wanted the easiest way, cut a stem, put it in water.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a vigorous tropical climber. It can be propagated in numerous ways:

- cuttings rooted in water
- cuttings rooted in a medium like vermiculite or perlite
- [layering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layering) where you root part of the stem in another pot

As long as you have a node on the stem this plant is not fussy, almost anything goes!

The one method of propagation that is unlikely when grown as a houseplant is setting seed. This plant will not flower unless it is grown in high light levels and has mature leaves.  A picture of the inflorescence of a relative is [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dragon-Tail_Plant_(Epipremnum_pinnatum)_6.jpg).

See my answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/7084/499) for more details.

It seems like you also want to know how to rejuvenate the plant. There are many ways:

- cut it back to the ground with at least one node on the stem
- cut the plant into sections with at least one node on the stem, root, pot up
- layer a stem back into the pot

This plant is tough so I like the methods that are the least work.  Put in  a higher light location and cut all the stems back hard to the pot with at least one node.  Reduce water and wait for new growth.

Comment: Additionally if you want to keep all that green canopy, after you have cut the stems back, trim the stem of the canopy to nice fresh green and stick the ends in a cup of water. You'll be rewarded with roots very quickly and will be able to pot them soon enough.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I added information on my immediate actions to the question.