# What is this plant and does it require a lot of sunshine?

Tags: identification, watering, houseplants

Could anyone help identify this plant? I had it in my previous apartment that was facing north. Now we placed it in front of the window facing east, where it gets much more sunshine that before.

Does this plant require a lot of sunshine, or should it be away from the window?
How often should it be watered?

Thank you.

P.S. These pictures were taken in the morning:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is [Money Plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum), also called as Pothos and has many names. It is easy to grow, requires very low care. Good for new gardeners. **It does not requires a lot of sunshine, grows very well indoors with low light.** You can practically keep it anywhere, even in water filled bottle. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQTxJ.jpg)

Water it moderately, just to ensure its soil is moist! But don't worry about it.

Read this answer for more details: [Help identifying this vine with green and white heart shaped leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/help-identifying-this-plant?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 4):

This is Scindapsus aureus, also known as Pothos as the first answer mentions, and Devils Ivy. It does not like direct sunlight, although it likes a bright spot. The reason I'm adding an answer is because your plant doesn't look good - it should be bushy with more than one stem either dangling or trailing, or trained up a support. I'd suggest you cut off about six to eight inches from the top, strip off the lower leaves and pop it in a bottle of water, with just the bottom part of the stem sitting in water. This will produce roots to make a new plant. In the meantime, cut back the rest of the plant, repot in new compost if you haven't done that in a while, water well, but don't leave it sitting in water for longer than 30 minutes, put it somewhere bright but out of direct sun, and wait for it to put on (lots and lots) of new growth. Feed weekly with houseplant food during growing season (spring and summer).

Comment: I agree, it looks like unfeeded from a day or two.