# What's the name of this common houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

This is a pretty common houseplant I think. I have a bunch of these all over the house, growing hydroponically and in soil. I'd like to learn more about these but don't know their name, any insight would be great.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plant is pothos or Epipremnum aureum.

More details can be found in these answers [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/help-identifying-this-plant/7083#7083), [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/what-is-this-plant-and-does-it-require-a-lot-of-sunshine/7582#7582) and [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7082/received-a-plant-need-help-identifying-it/7084#7084).